# Unfreeze bodies in Box2Djs or prevent from exiting world

Tags: javascript, node.js, box2d, physics

I am working on a server side physics experiment where the user controls an object through a socket. The problem I am running into results when the user moves the object outside the boundaries of the world.

I am using Box2Djs as installed through `npm`.

I create world 500x500 and then attach the following listener to it:

```
var boundaryListener = new b2d.b2BoundaryListener();
boundaryListener.Violation = function (body) {
    //we will move this body to the opposite side
    var position = body.GetWorldCenter();
    //snap to opposite side
    if (position.x < 0) {
        position.x = worldAABB.upperBound.x + position.x;
    }
    if (position.y < 0) {
        position.y = worldAABB.upperBound.y + position.y;
    }
    if (position.x > worldAABB.upperBound.x) {
        position.x -= worldAABB.upperBound.x;
    }
    if (position.y > worldAABB.upperBound.y) {
        position.y -= worldAABB.upperBound.y;
    }

    body.m_flags = body.m_flags & (~b2d.b2Body.e_frozenFlag); //does nothing :(
}
this.world.SetBoundaryListener(boundaryListener);
```

`worldAABB` is the b2AABB that the world uses as a boundary.

The problem is that I have noticed that when the boundary listener is fired, the flags are set to 22 which is allowSleep, frozen, and island flags. It would seem that when a b2Body passes outside the world boundary, it is frozen. That last line is an attempt to unfreeze the body by messing with the internal flags, but I have a distinct feeling that's the wrong way to do it.

How can I unfreeze the body? There are no functions that clear the frozen flags that I can see (the javascript is over 10,000 lines long so I honestly haven't read the whole thing) and placing some bodies as walls seems to have no effect (the user's object passes right through them).

My walls are created like so:

```
//create walls
var wallShape = new b2d.b2PolygonDef();
wallShape.SetAsBox(500, 10);
wallShape.density = 0.0;
wallShape.friction = 0.3;

var bodyDef = new b2d.b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.Set(250, 20);
var north = this.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
north.CreateShape(wallShape);

bodyDef = new b2d.b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.Set(250, 499);
var south = this.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
south.CreateShape(wallShape);

bodyDef = new b2d.b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.Set(499,250);
bodyDef.angle = Math.PI / 2;
var east = this.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
east.CreateShape(wallShape);

bodyDef = new b2d.b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.Set(1, 250);
bodyDef.angle = Math.PI / 2;
var west = this.world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
west.CreateShape(wallShape);
```

Does anyone have any insights on how to fix this? There is very very little documentation I can find on using Box2D in javascript aside from the flash documentation that the website points to (which doesn't match half the time) and the C++ documentation which doesn't even talk about freezing.

It would probably be helpful to mention that the world has no gravity and all the objects have some linear and angular damping (its supposed to be a psuedo-in-space feel).

Comment: Why you so care about this flag? Do you have invalid simulation or smth?

Comment: It causes the bodies to stop moving and I can't get them to stop moving again and that is the only flag that makes sense. The boundary listener was to try to snap to them to the opposite side so that they could keep moving.

Answer (score 0):

I had investigated Box2Djs source, and found next thing. Every time step Box2Djs checks if the body is inside the world boundaries. If body is out of range, then it "frozing", i.e. its excluding from collision detection. There this code (Body.js line 414):

```
Freeze: function(){
    this.m_flags |= b2Body.e_frozenFlag;
    this.m_linearVelocity.SetZero();
    this.m_angularVelocity = 0.0;

    for (var s = this.m_shapeList; s != null; s = s.m_next)
    {
        s.DestroyProxy();
    }
}
```

Pay attention, this check performs **every time step** (b2Island.js 244). So, if you set e_frozenFlag at boundary listener, it will do nothing: flag will be set up at next time step. Thats more, after body had frozen, it losses its veolcity and its shapes looses theirs proxies in broad phase (as you can see from code above). Looks like proxies are not restroing automaticly, so, reseting flag is not enough.

I also not found somewhere in Box2Djs interface or logic for unfreezing bodies. Doing this manually is some kind of dirty trick, because you should acces BroadPhase, which is Box2Djs internal. Thats more, it dont help you, because on freezing body losses its velociy. But, as I see, you need continue body moving.

Solution is next. You should prevent body frozing at all in order to keep body in simulation after it moved out of world boundaries. It may be done by next trick. First, set world boundary with some large value. Then, set contact listener, and when body touches the walls, perform your boundary violation logic.

How to set contact listener in C++ you can see there: https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks Sory, I dont know java script and can't say, how to do this in Box2Djs.